# CMD batch not liking error redirect

Tags: batch-file, windows-xp, cmd

I'm learning the ins and outs of batch programming, and I've hit a small snag.  I'm trying to recursively loop through a directory (and subdirs) to find suitable .vob files.  All is well, except my `dir` command is outputting `File Not Found`.  In the command line, I can redirect the error to oblivion using:

`dir /b *.vob 2>NUL`

In the batch file, however, I get the blink of death.

```
for /R %%G IN (\) DO (
    pushd "%%G"
    for /F "usebackq" %%V in (`dir /b *.vob`) DO (
        echo: Found %%~nV in %%~dpV
    )
    popd
)
```

Changing it to

```
for /R %%G IN (\) DO (
    pushd "%%G"
    for /F "usebackq" %%V in (`dir /b *.vob 2>NUL`) DO (
        echo: Found %%~nV in %%~dpV
    )
    popd
)
```

My cmd window, I assume, crashes.  Blinks on and off.

Debugging batches sucks, btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the redirect `2^>NUL`, then it should work as expected.

```
for /R %%G IN (\) DO (
    pushd "%%G"
    for /F "usebackq" %%V in (`dir /b *.vob 2^>NUL`) DO (
        echo: Found %%~nV in %%~dpV
    )
    popd
)
```